# Goals when payment is cancelled

Tags: opencart, analytics, goal-tracking

I have opencart 1.5.6. Analytics is running for a while now, but I want to implement the goals, but that's where it goes wrong.

The goal URL (starting with): `/index.php?route=checkout/success`

Unfortunately when a customer goes to the payment page, but doesn't proceed (either cancels or just leaves the payment page) they still go to that URL! So Google analytics sees it as a successful goal entry, but the back-end says "status = cancelled".

How can I make sure those goals aren't measured, while successful goals are measured?

One full URL of a cancelled order:

> /index.php?route=checkout/success&trxid=<TRXID>&ec=<EC>

One full URL of a successful order:

> /index.php?route=checkout/success&trxid=<TRXID>&ec=<EC>

So I can't differentiate between them according to the URLs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that user is redirected to this URL from a payment gateway, isn't he? Most of the medium to the best payment gateways have at least two return URLs - one for successful payment and one for failed/cancelled payment (e.g. *successURL* and *failURL*).

If this is the case then it is really easy to create a new `index.php?route=checkout/success/fail&trxid=...&ec=...` action by only creating a new method `public function fail() { ... }` in a `checkout/success` controller and use this URL as a *failURL* for Your payemnt gateway.